# React Native: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. Trying to pass state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I got two screens and want to pass the state from one to the other.

Simplified Screen 1:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { buttons } from '../../components/buttons/Buttons';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
       ...
        <TextInput onChange={(input) => this.setState({username: input})}></TextInput>
        ...
        <Button.main onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register', {username: this.state.username})} title='Create Account'/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, if I press the button, I want to pass `this.state.username` to the new screen. If I don't use `onChange={(input) => this.setState({username: input})}` and set a value for the username manually like this:

```
this.state = {
    username: 'Test',
}
```

The value gets passed without problem and I can access it from the new screen. But when I try to change `this.state.username` while the `TextInput` changes and then pass `this.state.username` I get the following warning:

Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `isTrusted` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

I don't know how to use `event.persist()` as proposed in the warning and the username doesn't get passed.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find a solution and I'm a beginner. I would be glad if someone could help me with this :)

Comment: where is the `event` object in your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using onChangeText instead of onChange.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to accepted answer to provide a more elaborate explanation.

The behaviour observed is a combination React's intended design for events and how Javascript uses the pass-by-reference concept for passing objects into function:

**React's design for events**

The context here is that the function is passed to the `onChange` handler rather than `onChangeText`. `onChange` will pass an **event object** to the function while `onChangeText` passes a String. There is a catch to how event objects works in React.

React uses `SyntheticEvent` for events passed into event handlers and `SyntheticEvent`s are pooled. So rather than creating new `SyntheticEvent` objects, these pooled objects are reused and all properties will be nullified after a callback is invoked ([see React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)).

**Pass-by-reference for objects in Javascript**

In Javascript, when an object gets passed into a function as argument, the function receives the reference to that object as parameter rather than creating a copy of the object. Thus, modifying the object in the function will lead to the original object being modified.

**Putting them together**

Setting the passed event object parameter to state is basically storing the reference to one of the event objects in the pool into state. Since this object is reused (modified) and its content does not persist for long, the content retrieved from the reference stored in the state will quickly become irrelevant. This will cause the app to behave in unexpected ways.

The development environment detects this and thus give a warning.

The use of `onChangeText` - like the accepted answer recommended - will not only solve the problem but also seemingly be closer the original intention of the code.